# How to stop a character from going out of the screen?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

i'm making this game where a ninja is supposed to go up and down. I wrote a method for a button to do so but the problem is that when the ninja is at the top of the screen (landscape)
it still goes up when i touch the up button so, i did this

```
-(void)upPressed:(id)sender
{
if(CGPointEqualToPoint(ninja.position, ccp(0,280)))
{
    id standStill = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:0 position:ccp(0,0)];
    [ninja runAction:standStill];
}else
{
id moveUp = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:.1 position:ccp(0,80)];
[ninja runAction:moveUp];
}
}
```

and the problem still exists. any help?

i.e when the ninja is at (0,280), i want the up button to do nothing

Comment: Tempted to answer with "Maybe ask him nicely?" :)

Answer (score 1):

You are testing for equality. This if condition will only be true if the ninja is exactly at `{0, 200}`.

Try this instead:

```
if (ninja.position.y < 280)
{
    // no need to run an action for this
    ninja.position = CGPointZero; 

    // but you should stop any potentially running (move) action
    [ninja stopAllActions];
}
else ...
```